# how to create a form popup-modal in magento2

Tags: magento2, widgets, modal

I am new to magento2. i'm trying to create a popup-modal for my new form. I have created a popup which works fine but unable to create a modal.

Following is the code for popup which loads on page load--

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
    ],
    function($, alert) {
       alert({
            title: "Some title",
            content: "we can show popuop based on cookies later",
            autoOpen: true,
            clickableOverlay: false,
            focus: "",
            actions: {
                always: function(){
                    console.log("modal closed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Please help me to create a modal. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Javascript and belongs on the general stackoverflow.com site

Answer (score 52):

Try below code:

```
<div id="popup-modal">
    <h1> Hi I'm here.... </h1>
</div>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'popup modal title',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

            $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: How to open div content on <a> tag onClick ?

Comment: @SHPatel Looking for the same solution, have you find it?

Comment: @Luis Garcia Yes I have solution

Comment: Yes You can put your question.

Comment: @SHPatel how can I get the form data? inside the `click: function () {                        this.closeModal();}` If i have `textbox` inside the `<div id="popup-modal">`?

Comment: @ how can I get the form data? inside the `click: function () { this.closeModal();}` If i have `textbox` inside the `<div id="popup-modal">`?

Comment: How can we use this script to open a pdf document in modal popup? We have the pdf included using WYSIWYG editor in a CMS page.

Comment: For some one who looking for translate for title but doesn't work, then use this instead: title: "<?php echo __('popup modal title')?>"

Answer (score 11):

You need to use Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal widget. See more details in [Official Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html)
Example:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($){
     $('<div />').html('Modal Window Content')
        .modal({
            title: 'My Title',
            autoOpen: true,
            closed: function () {
                // on close
            },
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Confirm',
                attr: {
                    'data-action': 'confirm'
                },
                'class': 'action-primary',
                click: clickCallback
            }]
         });
});
```

Comment: how i can creat edit form ui-component modal. No redirect by controller

Comment: how can I get the form data? inside the `click: function () { this.closeModal();}` If i have `textbox` inside the `<div id="popup-modal">`?

Comment: shall i call another function inside click function instead of this.closeModal()

Answer (score 7):

**Modal window popup in header area**

[image]

```
 <a href="#" id="click-header">
    View Video
</a>
<div id="header-mpdal" style="display:none;">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
        <iframe allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" gesture="media" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/P45AMKIW0ok" width="560">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script is here: -

```
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: '',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#header-mpdal'));
            $("#click-header").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#header-mpdal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

*since this is on a responsive site, I added a video Wrapper to make sure it's responsive.*

**Here is CSS to make that happen:**

```
.videoWrapper { position: relative;padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */padding-top: 25px;height: 0;
iframe {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create static block and insert the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
button {
    background-color: #0ea3d6;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <a href="#urlid"><button>Button</button></a>
        <div id="urlid" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <h2>Hand Tools</h2>
                <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
                <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
require(['Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'],
    function(confirm) {
        confirm({
            title: 'Confirm Dialog',
            content: "We need your confirmation there",
            actions: {
                confirm: function() { console.log('confirmed') },
                cancel: function() { console.log('canceled') }
            }
        });
);
</script>
```