# Magento 2 How to create a popup in checkout if customer is not logged in

Tags: magento2, checkoutsession

When a guest customer who is not logged in hits checkout, I want a popup to remind customers to login at the checkout page.

How do I implement it? What files should i override?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? Which Magento version are you using? What have you tried so far, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have in below post, how you can create a modal (popup) in Magento2:

[how to create a form popup-modal in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90842/how-to-create-a-form-popup-modal-in-magento2)