# Magento2 + modal confirmation popup after page load

Tags: magento2, varnish, popup, modal-popup, modal

I want to open modal confirmation dialogue and based on that I'm operating some database operation as my need. So please suggest me the best way to open modal confirmation popup that should work even varnish cache or any cache is there.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90842/how-to-create-a-form-popup-modal-in-magento2 you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

As refereed by @MichaelHa

Try this Code:

```
<div id="popup-modal">
    <h1> Hi I'm here.... </h1>
</div>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'popup modal title',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

            $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
        }
    );
</script>
```

Hope this will help You!!

Comment: Please don't take other people's answers.

Comment: Please check answer, Refereed by @MichaelHa