# Magento 2: How to open admin edit page in modal popup

Tags: magento2, ui-form, modal

To edit or create my data, I use the ui_component form as default. 
Now I try to open the admin edit page in a modal window, but unfortuantely I HAVE NO IDEA how to do this :-(
Please help!

Christian

Comment: Check this post with an answer if it helps!
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90842/how-to-create-a-form-popup-modal-in-magento2

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I want, is to open my ui-form with all buttons like as default, but in a modal window.